# ISDeploymentWizard status on silent mode

Tags: powershell, ssis

When running `ISDeploymentWizard.exe` in Silent mode from PowerShell, is there any way to capture error status?

Comment: How is this a PowerShell question?

Comment: I’m calling it from PowerShell, so the solution I prefer is a PowerShell script :)

Comment: Did you find solution for it? I raised similar question now: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67604718/how-to-have-ssis-exception-in-my-console-log

Comment: @arielma I don't recall.